Half plane model, distance between point and hyperbolic line
I'm currently reading chapter 3 of "Hyperbolic Geometry" by James W. Anderson, and try to do exercise 3.19. The crux is to solve the following problem.
We are in the half plane model $\mathbb{H}$. Let $l$ be the hyperbolic line included in the Euclidean circle, with center $0$ and radius $1$. And let $p \in \mathbb{H}$ be a point on the imaginary axis $I$ with $\lambda=\text{Im}(p)>1$. We want to determine the distance from $p$ to $l$.
The pointwise distance is already defined to be $d_{\mathbb{H}}(z_1,z_2)=\left|ln \left|\frac{(x_1-c-r) y_2}{y_1 (x_2-c-r)}\right|\right|$ with $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{H}$ and $z_k=x_k+y_ki$. Here, $c$ is the center of the circle centered on $\mathbb{R}$ connecting $z_1$, and $z_2$ and $r$ its radius. The setwise distance is defined to be $d_{\mathbb{H}}(X,Y)=\text{inf} \{ d_{\mathbb{H}}(x,y) | x\in X,y\in Y \}$.
The goal is to show that the shortest distance (infimum) from $X=p$ to $Y=l$ occurs when we pick the distance $d_{\mathbb{H}}(p,i)$.
To show this, we let $e^{i\phi}\in l$ vary and calculate the distance $d_{\mathbb{H}}(e^{i\phi}, p)$. We see that, $c=\frac{1-\lambda^2}{2cos(\phi)}$ and $r=\sqrt{c^2+\lambda^2}$. Plugging this into our pointwise distance formula gives:
$d_{\mathbb{H}}(e^{i\phi}, p)=\left|ln \left|\frac{(cos(\phi)-c-r) \lambda}{sin(\phi) (-c-r)}\right|\right|=\left|ln \left|\frac{\left(cos(\phi)-\frac{1-\lambda^2}{2cos(\phi)}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-\lambda^2}{2cos(\phi)}\right)^2+\lambda^2}\right) \lambda}{sin(\phi) \left(-\frac{1-\lambda^2}{2cos(\phi)}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-\lambda^2}{2cos(\phi)}\right)^2+\lambda^2}\right)}\right|\right|$.
The book states that, with "a lot of algebraic massage" we derive the following shorter expression:
$d_{\mathbb{H}}(e^{i\phi}, p)=\ln\left(\cosh(\ln(\lambda)) \csc(\phi)+\sqrt{ \cosh^{2}(\ln(\lambda)) \csc^{2}(\phi)-1}\right)$
The problem is that I can't prove that these two terms are equal and have no idea how this algebraic massage looks like. I plotted both functions in GeoGebra and they are the same.
The derivative of $d_{\mathbb{H}}(e^{i\phi}, p)$ is negative for $0<\phi\leq \pi/2$. I checked this for the second (shorter) expression (and in GeoGebra). Therefore, $d_{\mathbb{H}}(e^{i\phi}, p)$ achieves its unique minimum at $\phi= \pi/2$.
For GeoGebra copy-paste:
first function: ln(cosh(ln(a)) csc(x)+sqrt(cosh^(2)(ln(a)) csc^(2)(x)-1))
and second function:
g(x)=abs(ln abs((((cos(x)-((1-a^(2))/(2 cos(x)))-sqrt((((1-a^(2))/(2 cos(x))))^(2)+a^(2))) a)/(sin(x) (-((1-a^(2))/(2 cos(x)))-sqrt((((1-a^(2))/(2 cos(x))))^(2)+a^(2)))))))

When I run the two functions you provided on Desmos, they do not have the same graph. The first one tends to 0 as $\lambda \to \infty$, while the second one goes to $\infty$. I assume that the closing bracket of the second formula is supposed to be placed after the root symbol, right?

Thank you, I fixed the bracket. Feel free to post a picture of the Desmos plot, when I copy paste in GeoGebra the graphs are the same, also for big $\lambda$

Ok, let's start with
$$
\cosh(\ln(\lambda)) = \frac{\lambda + \lambda^{-1}}{2} = \frac{1+\lambda^2}{2\lambda}.
$$
Next up, let's take a closer look at the root expression
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{\cosh(\ln(\lambda))^2}{\sin(\phi)^2}-1} &= \sqrt{\frac{(1+\lambda^2)^2 - 4\lambda^2 \sin(\phi)^2}{4 \lambda^2 \sin(\phi)^2}} \\
& = \sqrt{(1+\lambda^2)^2 - 4\lambda^2 + 4 \lambda^2 - 4\lambda^2 \sin(\phi)^2}\frac{1}{2\lambda \sin(\phi)} \\
&= \sqrt{(1-\lambda^2)^2 + 4\lambda^2(1-\sin(\phi)^2)}\frac{1}{2\lambda \sin(\phi)} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{(1-\lambda^2)^2 }{4 \cos(\phi)^2} + \lambda^2}\cdot\frac{2\cos(\phi)}{2\lambda \sin(\phi)} = \frac{r \cos(\phi)}{\lambda \sin(\phi)}.
\end{align}
Now, let's take a look at the inverse of the $\cosh$ expression (for $\phi \in [0,\pi/2]$, otherwise take the expression directly, without inverses)
\begin{align}
\left( \frac{\cosh(\ln(\lambda))}{\sin(\phi)} + \sqrt{\frac{\cosh(\ln(\lambda))^2}{\sin(\phi)^2}-1} \right)^{-1} & = \left( \frac{(1+\lambda^2) + 2 r \cos(\phi)}{2 \lambda \sin(\phi)} \right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{2 \lambda \sin(\phi)}{(1+\lambda^2)+2r\cos(\phi)}\frac{(1+\lambda^2)-2r\cos(\phi)}{(1+\lambda^2)+2r\cos(\phi)} \\
&= \frac{2 \lambda \sin(\phi)(1 + \lambda^2) - 4r \lambda \sin(\phi) \cos(\phi)}{(1+\lambda^2)^2- 4r^2\cos(\phi)^2} \\
&= \frac{2\lambda \sin(\phi) (1 + \lambda^2 - 2r\cos(\phi))}{(1+\lambda^2)^2 - 4(1-\lambda^2)^2 - 4\lambda^2 \cos(\phi)^2} \\
&= \frac{2\lambda \sin(\phi) (1 + \lambda^2 - 2r\cos(\phi))}{4\lambda^2(1- \cos(\phi)^2)} \\
&= \frac{1 +\lambda^2 -2r \cos(\phi)}{2\lambda\sin(\phi)}\cdot \frac{c+r}{c+r} \\
&= \frac{(1+\lambda^2)(c+r) -(1-\lambda^2)r - (c(1-\lambda^2) + 2\lambda^2 \cos(\phi) }{2\lambda\sin(\phi)(c+r)} \\
&= \frac{2\lambda^2(c+r) -2 \lambda^2\cos(\phi)}{2\lambda\sin(\phi)(c+r)} \\
&= \frac{\lambda(\cos(\phi) - c - r)}{\sin(\phi)(-c -r)}
\end{align}
Now take the logarithm which turns the inverse into a minus, which in turn gets absorbed by the absolute value.
